# How to take only unique elements from a list?

Tags: list, haskell, functional-programming, unique

I have a list, say `[1,2,3,4,3,2,4]`.
I would like to output every element once, for example `[1,2,3,4]`.
How can I do this in Haskell?

Comment: Take a look at `nub`: https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Data-List.html#v:nub

Comment: Thankf, completely forgot about it. It will suffice for this case, because I'm not working with a lot of date

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can make use of [**`nub :: Eq a => [a] -> [a]`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Data-List.html#v:nub) which acts as a *uniqness filter*. It will however require *O(n<sup>2</sup>)* since it does not use a data structure like a hashset.

For example:

```
Prelude Data.List> nub [1,2,3,4,3,2,4]
[1,2,3,4]
```

If the elements are of a type that is a member of the [**`Hashable`** typeclass](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/classy-prelude-1.5.0/docs/ClassyPrelude.html#t:Hashable), you can use for example [**`hashNub :: (Eq a, Hashable a) => [a] -> [a]`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/classy-prelude-1.5.0/docs/ClassyPrelude.html#v:hashNub) to perform a uniqness filter in *O(n log n)*:

```
Prelude ClassyPrelude> hashNub [1,2,3,4,3,2,4]
[1,2,3,4]
```

Comment: Like `hashNub`, there is also [`nubOrd` and `nubInt`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/containers-0.6.2.1/docs/Data-Containers-ListUtils.html#v:nubOrd) from the `containers` package which use a `Set` and an `IntSet` respectively to achieve the same *O(n log n)* complexity. (It looks like `hashNub` requires either the `classy-prelude` or the `witherable` package.)

Comment: Also `nubOrdOn` and `nubIntOn`, which let you categorize elements of the list and take only the first from each category.

Answer (score 11):

You can do it with sets using Data.set:

```
import qualified Data.Set as Set
lst = [1,2,3,4,1,2,3]
y =  Set.fromList lst
```

The output is:

```
y
=> fromList [1,2,3,4]
```

Answer (score 5):

There is a [`nub`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Data-List.html#v:nub) function exactly for that. However, it has complexity of O(n^2), which is not so good. In case of numbers (or any `Ord` type) you can make your own `unique` function like this:

```
unique :: Ord a => [a] -> [a]
unique = map head . group . sort
```

You'll need to import `Data.List`.
It acts like this:

```
sort [1,2,3,1,2] -> [1,1,2,2,3]        -- to order the elements
group [1,1,2,2,3] -> [[1,1],[2,2],[3]] -- to group equal ones
map head [[1,1],[2,2],[3]] -> [1,2,3]  -- to take first of groups
```

That has complexity of O(n log n), which is a way better.

Comment: Or just `nubOrd`?

Comment: @JosephSible-ReinstateMonica or so :)

Answer (score 2):

Basically since `sort`ing in Haskell lists are quite fast (best case O(n) worst case O(nlogn) we might use sorting first and then folding for an efficient solution with an additional effect of getting a sorted result, if that would be beneficial.

The following code is for minimal `cons` operations;

```
Prelude Data.List
λ> :{
λ| foldr (\e rs -> case rs of
λ|                 []     -> [e]
λ|                 (x:xs) -> if x == e then rs else e:rs) [] $ sort [8,8,4,3,2,3,3,2,1,8,3,5]
λ| :}
[1,2,3,4,5,8]
```

and the following is, as per pointed out by @Joseph Sible-Reinstate Monica for *enhanced* laziness.

```
Prelude Data.List
λ> :{
λ| foldr (\e rs -> e : case rs of
λ|                 []     -> []
λ|                 (x:xs) -> if x == e then xs else rs) [] $ sort [8,8,4,3,2,3,3,2,1,8,3,5]
λ| :}
[1,2,3,4,5,8]
```

Comment: @Joseph Sible-Reinstate Monica Thanks for the editing but if i am not mistaken, this version seems to make cons operation per item of the source list while the previous one does cons once per item of the results list which is (sometimes much) shorter in case there are duplicates.

Comment: Yeah, I guess there is a bit of a trade-off here, of yielding the results earlier vs. allocating less. I personally prefer the former, but feel free to revert if you're not a fan.